# Google Apps debug window is only showing 10 object/array properties

Tags: arrays, debugging, object, google-apps-script

I'm finding it difficult to debug my code because I can only seem to get the debugger to show the first 10 properties in an object or array. This seems to be a new issue as I do a lot of debugging and used to have moments where I would expand an object's/array's properties in the debug window and it would make chrome slow down as it expanded all the properties. It now doesn't slow chrome down but it also doesn't show all the information I need.

[image]

The above image shows what I mean. This array now shows an ellipses where the rest of the properties should be. I logged `ordersResult.length` and the array actually has a length of 1000. If I expand one of the objects in the array I will get the same ellipses after 10 properties.

I can't find any information about this change but does anyone know a way to expand my arrays and objects to their full extent (*I don't want to resort to logging as that will really slow down my debugging*)? I've tried the '*Show all Data*' button, but that just displays a list of functions that can be used on the array/object; the ellipses remain.

***Edit:*** As per Mogsdad's suggestion I have added this to the issue tracker ([Issue 5562](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5562&thanks=5562&ts=1448554712))

Comment: I suggest you add this to the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), and come back here with the issue number. Hopefully Google fixes it faster than usual...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Mogsdad, I have done this now.